# SQLite query to get the closest datetime

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime

I am trying to write an SQLite statement to get the closest datetime from an user input (from a WPF datepicker). I have a table IRquote(rateId, quoteDateAndTime, quoteValue).

For example, if the user enter 10/01/2000 and the database have only fixing stored for 08/01/2000, 07/01/2000 and 14/01/2000, it would return 08/01/2000, being the closest date from 10/01/2000.

Of course, I'd like it to work not only with dates but also with time.

I tried with this query, but it returns the row with the furthest date, and not the closest one:

```
SELECT quoteValue FROM IRquote 
WHERE rateId = '" + pRefIndexTicker + "'
ORDER BY abs(datetime(quoteDateAndTime) - datetime('" + DateTimeSQLite(pFixingDate) + "')) ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Note that I have a function DateTimeSQLite to transform user input to the right format.

I don't get why this does not work.
How could I do it? Thanks for your help

Comment: From where are you getting this user input? Where is the data stored?

Comment: I'm not sure of all of the SQL commands to do this, but I suspect there must be some way to diff the input with the stored values, derive a numeric value from that, sort by that value (`ORDER BY`), and take the first record (`TOP 1`).  (Optionally convert to an absolute value before sorting in case you want the closest time in either direction.)

Comment: @BerndLinde I edited my question to add more details. 

David I'll try again with your proposed method. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the closest date, you will need to use the **[strftime('%s', datetime)](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)** SQLite function.

With [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/40935/5) example/demo, you will get the most closest date to your given date.
Note that the date `2015-06-25 10:00:00` is the input datetime that the user selected.

```
select t.ID, t.Price, t.PriceDate,
       abs(strftime('%s','2015-06-25 10:00:00') - strftime('%s', t.PriceDate)) as 'ClosestDate'
  from Test t
 order by abs(strftime('%s','2015-06-25 10:00:00') - strftime('%s', PriceDate))
 limit 1;
```

SQL explanation:
We use the `strftime('%s') - strftime('%s')` to calculate the difference, in seconds, between the two dates (*Note:* it has to be '%s', not '%S'). Since this can be either positive or negative, we also need to use the `abs` function to make it all positive to ensure that our `order by` and subsequent `limit 1` sections work correct.

Comment: Highly inefficient, converting datetimes to strings.

Comment: @ypercube SQLite stores DateTime as string, so there is no conversion actually happening. There is no DateTime type in SQLite

Comment: I've added an answer with a query that can use an index on the column (and thnx for the fiddle, I used it, too ;)

Comment: `strftime('%s', t.PriceDate)` does a conversion by the way. Using functions (strftime, abs) on columns makes any index unusable for the query.

Comment: I had to write 'order by ClosestDate' for this to work for me; otherwise great, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If the table is big, and there is an index on the datetime column, this will use the index to get the 2 closest rows (above and below the supplied value) and will be more efficient:

```
select * 
from
  ( select * 
    from 
    ( select t.ID, t.Price, t.PriceDate
      from Test t
      where t.PriceDate <= datetime('2015-06-23 10:00:00') 
      order by t.PriceDate desc
      limit 1
    ) d
  union all
    select * from
    ( select t.ID, t.Price, t.PriceDate
      from Test t
      where t.PriceDate > datetime('2015-06-23 10:00:00') 
      order by t.PriceDate asc
      limit 1
    ) a
  ) x
order by abs(julianday('2015-06-23 10:00:00') - julianday(PriceDate))
limit 1 ;
```

Tested in [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/e068a/2).

Comment: I tested your solution with 500 tables and around 150 rows in each (in fact, with time column rather than datetime column). For me, the solution of @BerndLinde is around 40% quicker. I tested various indexes: on column, on time(column), on strftime('%s',column) and none of them has any performance improvement.

Comment: 150 rows is such a tiny table, so how much difference was there? Did both queries run in milliseconds?

Answer (score 2):

Another useful solution is using *BETWEEN* operator, if you can determine upper and lower bounds for your time/date query. I encountered this solution just recently here in this [link](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-between/). This is what i've used for my application on a time column named t (changing code for date column and date function is not difficult):

```
select *
from myTable 
where t BETWEEN '09:35:00' and '09:45:00' 
order by ABS(strftime('%s',t) -  strftime('%s','09:40:00')) asc 
limit 1
```

Also, i must correct my comment on above post. I tried  a simple examination of speed of these 3 approaches proposed by @BerndLinde, @ypercubeᵀᴹ and me . I have around 500 tables with 150 rows in each and medium hardware in my PC. The result is:

1. Solution 1 (using strftime) takes around 12 seconds.
2. Adding index of column t to solution 1 improves speed by around 30% and takes around 8 seconds. I didn't face any improvement for using index of time(t).
3. Solution 2 also has around 30% of speed improvement over Solution 1 and takes around 8 seconds
4. Finally, Solution 3 has around 50% improvement and takes around 5.5 seconds. Adding index of column t gives a little more improvement and takes around 4.8 seconds. Index of time(t) has no effect in this solution.

**Note:** I'm a simple programmer and this is a simple test in .NET code. A real performance test must consider more professional aspects, which i'm not aware of them. There was also some computations in my code, after querying and reading from database. Also, as @ypercubeᵀᴹ states, this result my not work for large amount of data.