# SQFlite rawquery to get the closest datetime

Tags: flutter, strftime, sqflite

I'm programming a birthday app and want to use sqflite to sort the nearest date.
Through the page: [SQLite query to get the closest datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31031561/sqlite-query-to-get-the-closest-datetime)
I found out about strftime, but unfortunately I don't know how to use it with Flutter. Here are some examples how to sort a date and how I try to find the current date with strftime.

```
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getSortDateMapListToDate(bool sort) async {
    Database db = await this.database;
    String sortingDirection = '$colDate DESC';
    if(!sort) {
      sortingDirection = '$colDate ASC';
    }

    DateTime test = DateTime.now();
    //var result = await db.query(dateTable, orderBy: sortingDirection);
    var result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * from $dateTable orderBy abs(strftime("%s",$test) - strftime("%s", $colDate))');
    return result;
  }
```

Maybe there is another possibility or someone has already worked with rawquerys and strftime.

For any kind of tip or help I would be grateful.

EDIT:
With the help from @heitor murara i edit my code:

```
var result = await db.rawQuery(
        "SELECT s.id, s.name, s.date, s.priority, (strftime('%y-%m-%d', '2020-06-30') - strftime('%y-%m-%d', s.$colDate)) as 'TestDate' "
        "FROM $dateTable s "
        "ORDER BY  TestDate"
    );
```

the dates i use: 30.06.2020  and with strftime('%s) i get the rows:

- 2015-08-15   // 32 remaining days
- 2010-11-03   // 126 remaining days
- 2010-07-10   // 10 remaining days
- 1994-07-17   // 17 remaining days
- 1993-06-29   // 364 remaining days

with strftime('%y-%m-%d) i get the rows:

- 1994-07-17   // 17 remaining days
- 1993-06-29   // 364 remaining days
- 2015-08-15   // 32 remaining days
- 2010-11-03   // 126 remaining days
- 2010-07-10   // 10 remaining days

what I am trying to achieve:

- 2010-07-10   // 10 remaining days
- 1994-07-17   // 17 remaining days
- 2015-08-15   // 32 remaining days
- 2010-11-03   // 126 remaining days
- 1993-06-29   // 364 remaining days

a other solution that is in my mind, would be a trigger, who "check" every day if the date changes, the remaining days are calculated dynamically.

Has someone a hint? :)

Answer (score 0):

The `strftime()` function you are using do this:

> The strftime() routine returns the date formatted according to the format string specified as the first argument.

So, if all your dates were in a format like this: `2020-06-28` you could run a rawQuery simply like this to make the ordering:

```
SELECT d FROM datetime_text ORDER BY d ASC;
```

However, if they are not, you can then use the `strftime()` function to format your date to than order:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', d) FROM datetime_text ORDER BY d ASC;
```

The dates would be returned in something like this:

```
2020-06-27
2020-06-28
2020-06-28
2020-06-28
2020-06-29
```

In your example, I believe you can achieve what you want with something like this:

```
var result = await db.rawQuery("SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', <column-name>) FROM $dateTable ORDERBY $sortingDirection");
```

As you can see I replaced the `*` from your query by a `<column-name>` just update it with your column name.

*Ps.: Since you are working with birthdays, the format `'%Y-%m-%d'` will do the job, you don't need to use times also.*

Comment: Thank you. Your tip, has brought me further but unfortunately not yet achieved the desired result.

Comment: What's missing?

Comment: Sorry the delay, been through a cyclone here... No need to use the subtraction structure in your query, nor mocking the `2020-06-30` date, doesn't make sense, just use `ORDER BY` as in the example

Comment: Something like this I imagine: "SELECT id, name, (strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date)), priority FROM $dateTable ORDER BY date ASC"

Comment: Unfortunately this query only gives a sorted sequence for the age. Nevertheless I thank you, I have now written a query that gives the desired result.